# Returning IQueryable expressions without executing database queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures, iqueryable

While curious about the use IQueryable hoping to improve existing code performance, I came across this [online test case](https://tests4geeks.com/c-sharp-online-test).

In order to test the validity of the proposed example, I:

- created two stored procedures
- called them as follows:

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      GetCustomers();
      GetRules();
  }

  public static IQueryable GetCustomers()
  {
      var db = new DbEntities();
      return db.GetCustomers().AsQueryable();
  }

  public static IQueryable GetRules()
  {
      var db = new DbEntities();
      return db.GetRules(null).AsQueryable();
  }
  ```
- Traced the db calls in SQL Server Profiler

According to the sample test question provided in the link

> As a result, we execute a single complex query against the database (when .ToList() is called) instead of retrieving two collections separately and joining them server-side.

I understood that as long as we are returning IQueryable, no db calls will be initiated until .ToList() is called *at one point*.

However, in the code example I provided:

- **GetRules** always calls the db and executes the procedure regardless the order in which the method is called, before or after GetCustomers
- **GetCustomers** does not call the db and execute the procedure until the console app is ready to exit.

[image]

My expectation is that non of these db calls should have taken place in first place because I am returning IQueryable.

***What is going on?***

Comment: Just because you use `AsQueryable` doesn't mean that what was before is `IQueryable`. What's the *return type* for `GetRules` and for `GetCustomers`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, the types are ObjectResult<GetRules_Result> and ObjectResult<GetCustomers_Result>

Comment: Can you see whether those implement `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, public class ObjectResult<T> : ObjectResult, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable

Comment: So you see, they are not `IQueryable` so the queries are executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of composable queries only really works for dynamic queries based on expression trees. If you call a stored procedure, you're *actually calling a stored procedure* - the fact that you had to add `.AsQueryable()` usually means that you're actually using LINQ-to-Objects on a *fully materialized object* (such as a `List<Customer>` or similar), but simply *describing* it as queryable. At that point: it is too late - you already executed it.

It *may* be possible to compose stored procedures somehow, but I wouldn't rely on it. That isn't really the target scenario when people talk about `IQueryable<T>`. Rather the intended usage is for things like:

```
IQueryable<Customer> CustomersByRegion(string region)
   => db.Customers.Where(c => c.Region == region);
...
var data = from cust in CustomersByRegion("North")
           where cust.Value > 10000
           order by cust.Name
           select new {cust.Id, cust.Name};
```

whereby the two separate `where` get composed with the `order by` and the sub-selection of columns to create a *composed* SQL query something like:

```
select Id, Name
from Customers
where Region = @p0 and Value > @p1
order by Name
```